# Converting Raw Image String Data to an Image

Tags: java, rest

I hit an API to get an image response and i take this image response as a string, the string is in it's raw format and not in a base 64 encoded format. How can i convert this string to an Image file.

I have aldready tried converting the string to byte array and then writing it into a file but that dint work and make the image file unreadable.

```
String Response = null;
    if (RequestMethod.POST.name().equalsIgnoreCase(requestMethod)) {
                    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(paymentRequest,httpHeaders);
    System.out.println(httpEntity.toString());
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,String.class);
                    if(responseEntity.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.FOUND)) {
                        Response=APPConstants.REDIRECT_RESPONSE.replace("{Location}", responseEntity.getHeaders().getLocation().toString());
    }else {
        Response =responseEntity.getBody();
        }
    }
```

This is the body that I get for the image when displayed

```
\u0089PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0001\u001d\u0000\u0000\u0001\u001d\u0001\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000b¤!8\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0006PLTEÿÿÿ\u0000\u0000\u0000UÂÓ~\u0000\u0000\u0000\tpHYs\u0000\u0000\u000eÄ\u0000\u0000\u000eÄ\u0001\u0095+\u000e\u001b\u0000\u0000\u0003]IDATh\u0081íYË\u008d«@\u0010l\u008bÃ\u001c\ta2\u0081Ä\u0090@\"1;\u0013BàÈÁr¿ªjXÏî&Ðoå9à\u0081)\u000eíþU5f\u009fõY\u007f~õîþ²y+¯Þ7\u007føb¸<ëaý\u008a\u0013Ü¦\u0005ág°n+w q\u008bóÁ¦j£¯[\u009cf\u0005\u00ad~\fýÓün\u0016G\u0087á\u009dã\u0086\u009d¿²\u0083`\u000e\u009c\u0001·øÞy¡;ì¶wÿ\u0003hv\u0083\u0089´.\u0090ð\u0088e\u0007)\u009e¬âhÞ\u008eA\u001e\u0081\u0089\u008a±\u001fA\u0097\fÄ\fî\u0011EÃ¯Ë\u008f4O\u0006:MD\u00adÁB\u0011B.?v\u0018{ï\u009bó\u008c VJ.¦¬\u001f£r\u0000A\u0005ß \u0012\r\u0099A+\u009f.\u0086§fÇ(Ãl2¤ÄÓ\u008aï¹A,=\u0007-\tëF¼S\u0018JGSìÓ\u0081`\töO\u009d³ÎOµ°z2¨L\u0097Ä YÇêîò\u0003\u008b\u0010#\u000b\u0019üð%-\b\u0086\u0099Bé¶OÊÛ*~\u0083ÒCjsÅSFÐÊ\f^êÅeæà\u0005ì¶Þ´²| =í\u0015@3é\u0098ÕpÆ¸3²®xJ\bR3Ú'+2\u0087<\u0012?+w]Ô¤¬ ìq¾nª\u0099b5\u0085ï\u001câ7·ë/H\b¢GøÔ\u0086àd¤ïØÉK\ryÈ\u0007\"{d+E¶Î\u0014Lg\u0014©\u008e\u0092È§\u0005¡Ö@ÚÁ\u0005ä_t\u000b{l·\u001d§\fYò\u0082°·oú\u000enQPY-îyAèRLÙMvJm\u0088û¢\\úÛº\u0094 «ª\u0099¨\u0094\bÿ×©IãüMh\u0012\u0082Ô\u009b\u0018J¨\u008f5t\u0007\u008fdñ;\u009e2\u0082\u0096\u0093\u0089\u0011DUGVÓé\u009d\u0086\u0017¤\u0004Uµ%UJñHM38DjD`F\u0090ã<d?ü\u0000¾\u001ey\u000bc5È°Ì 1± \u0004¤^ÒJ\u0085;ÔþÄ \u0085m\t\rê\u00113\ft©»\u0089\u0005»\u0097&\u009eò\u0081V6ÕN.¨êRaÓ\u0000\u00905]*\u001d\u0088½é\u0006õÌA®Îil·\u009d\u0012õM\u0090Ó\u0081Ä\u0006Àj4VÔ\u0094\u0091¼\u0080BÃÛa^>P\fæ¦\u0098\u001aÁ7ê¶\u000bÅtçÉA¡6ÄÒC\u009d>¢AñÖ\u0013\u0083¦\u0018\u0013]\u0083\u008c'ã)2xkf\u0018ù@\n\u001bªS*Q\u0098\u0003\u009bF\u008dt\u0083\u001c,yA \u008b\u009c\u0082\u009e\u001e\tÝÑ\u00850ý6ÃÈ\u0006\u0082Gôq+&0¨\u0094Ê`q_î\u0012\u0083¨ï\\¡DªÎ\u009aÉ¼8»T+L\u0093\u0081hØÈÎJ\u0006#&V^¿ÔFFÐ\u0089t±`ª\r²\u0081³p¾ã)!(¾·\u0090ñ\u0086¢^ÏOsÃÉ(ó\u0082\u0016\u0091\u0097\rG\bª!¨Í\u001c¡ÔJ\u0092| \u0089Ð\u0018Ìm\u008d¢f\"\u001c_nË\n²9\u0086u\u001ad0\u0083k\u0004Õ=;\u0088\u0096Ä$]ßÍiÝÃ\u007fL\u008dÒ\u0081\u0096k\u001eÊªCs\n\u009bV(\u0090/ë2\u0082\u0094Á\"íÜ\u0099Y|\u00836NeÞ\u00855\u001fè³>ëO¯\u007f\u0006'«#¾ í\u009f\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000IEND®B`\u0082
```

Comment: Well, if you're getting "raw" data you're probably getting a byte stream so don't try to interpret that as a string. If it's really meant to be a string then you should check what encoding this is meant to be - non using base64 or something similar to encode bytes into a string it quite unusual. If there's a documentation for that API you'd need to refer to that or ask the API provider how you're meant to use that api.

Comment: Found The Issue, Me handling it as a string and converting it to bytes was not the problem, but the encoding of the bytes were in "ISO_8859_1" but i was trying to get the bytes in "UTF-8" and so the file was not created properly.